# What is max and min range for double.valueOf()?

Tags: apex, double

what is max and min range for double.valueOf() in apex.

Answer (score 17):

According to the [Primitive Data Type docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_primitives.htm):

> **Double**
>   A 64-bit number that includes a decimal point. Doubles have a minimum
>   value of -2^63 and a maximum value of (2^63)-1

So. (2^63)-1 gives 9223372036854775807 and -2^63 gives -9223372036854775808 if you have no decimal value.

The docs also say:

> Note that scientific notation (e) for Doubles is not supported.

The [docs for double.valueOf()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_double.htm) say (my emphasis):

> Returns a Double that contains the value of the specified String. **As
>   in Java, the String is interpreted as representing a signed decimal.**

Given all this you would expect something like the following to throw an exception:

```
string maxDoubleString = '9323372036854775806';
Double maxDouble = double.valueof(maxDoubleString);
System.debug(maxDouble);
```

Yet you get:

> 21:22:17.040 (40038000)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[1](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_primitives.htm)|maxDoubleString|"9323372036854775806"
>   21:22:17.040 (40044000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[2](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_double.htm)
>   21:22:17.040 (40192000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[2](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_double.htm)|Double.valueOf(String)
>   21:22:17.040 (40225000)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[2](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_double.htm)|Bytes:12
>   21:22:17.040 (40236000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[2](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_double.htm)|Double.valueOf(String)
>   21:22:17.040 (40254000)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[2](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_double.htm)|maxDouble|9.323372036854776E18
>   21:22:17.040 (40259000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html)
>   21:22:17.040 (40277000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html)|System.debug(ANY)
>   21:22:17.040 (40293000)|USER_DEBUG|[3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html)|DEBUG|9.323372036854776E18

And then you scratch your head for a bit and think that looks like scientific notation and more bits than would fit in a 64 bit signed double... Indeed, we've lost some decimal places to accommodate the notation.

So while you can't create a literal double using scientific notation you can create one outside the documented range using scientific notation and double.valueOf(). E.g.

```
Double myPlannedLottoWinnings = double.valueof('9.9E102');
```

*Note that it is normally a bad idea to store currency values in a double due to the potential loss of precision.*

At this stage my best guess for the maximum and minimum values would match those for Java.

The [double docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) for Java gives:

- MAX_VALUE as (2-2^-52)·2^1023
  Which a few minutes on the abacus gives as 1.797693134862315708145274237317e+308
- MIN_VALUE as 2-1074
  4.9406564584124654417656879286822e-324

What I can say is that:

- `Double maxDouble = double.valueof('1.0E308');`

  > "VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[1](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_primitives.htm)|maxDouble|1.0E308"
- `Double maxDouble = double.valueof('1.0E309');`

  > "VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[1](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_primitives.htm)|maxDouble|Infinity"
- `Double maxDouble = double.valueof('1.7976931348623157e+308d');`

  > "VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[1](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_primitives.htm)|maxDouble|1.7976931348623157E308"
- `Double maxDouble = double.valueof('1.7976931348623158e+308d');`

  > "VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[1](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_primitives.htm)|maxDouble|1.7976931348623157E308"
  >   No, that isn't a typo, two different inputs have produced the same result.
- `Double maxDouble = double.valueof('1.7976931348623159e+308d');`

  > "VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[1](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_primitives.htm)|maxDouble|Infinity"
- `Double minDouble = double.valueof('4.94065645841246544e-324d');`  >"VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[1](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_primitives.htm)|minDouble|4.9E-324"

See also: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) for details about a "double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point".

Comment: Great point on not using Double (floating point) for currency.  In Apex there is Decimal which is [Java's BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) and will not have the loss of precision.

Comment: @PeterKnolle I thought I better note that based on my chosen variable name :) . I do find it odd that the documented maximum and minimum values only apply to literal doubles and not those created using `double.valueOf()`.